# keep adbanner at bottom on all orientation in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, admob, adbannerview

Iam trying to place one adbanner(admob banner) on bottom of my app.But currently by using my code it appearing sometimes at bottom or middle like that.Please check following screenshots
[image]

[image]

please check my code

```
#import "LocViewController.h"
@interface LocViewController ()
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation1;

}
@end
 #define MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID @"a152a98e7f64210"

@implementation LocViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //Do what you want in Landscape Left
        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];
        bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0,678,bannerView_.frame.size.width,bannerView_.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //Do what you want in Portrait
        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0,934,bannerView_.frame.size.width,bannerView_.frame.size.height);
    }
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
-(void)showAd:(NSString *)orient{
    // Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.

    if([orient isEqualToString:@"l"]){
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];
    bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0,678,bannerView_.frame.size.width,bannerView_.frame.size.height);
    }else{
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0,934,bannerView_.frame.size.width,bannerView_.frame.size.height);
    }
    // Specify the ad unit ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)

    {
        //load the portrait view
        [self showAd:@"p"];
    }
    else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)

    {
        //load the landscape view
        [self showAd:@"l"];

    }
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```